Microsoft Surface Pro 9 stays on after shutdown
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Microsoft Surface Pro 9. In the last couple of weeks something was updated in Ubuntu that now makes the Surface either not fully shut down or turn back on after shutdown.
I tried:

Updating to 24.10 - same effect
sudo shutdown -h now - same effect
Installing Linux Mint - Yeah, no.
Reinstalling fresh Ubuntu 24.04.1 fully formatted hard drive and it still has the same problem

What I have seen that I can't try:
Disable WOL (MS BIOS does not allow this type of configuring)
I was trying to see if there was a log or something I could review to see what is either staying on or turning on after shutdown.
This is making the Surface useless as it heats up on my backpack, flatlines the battery and it is useless without hauling around the power block and never actually shuts off.
I tried shutting down thes Surface, then using the command sudo journalctl -b -1 -e and looking over the information, I am not able to interpret it with an expert eye. Nothing is timing out that I can see.
The computer never cools down when using the shutdown from the top bar. When I use the sudo shutdown command, it does cool off. In both cases, it heats back up/stays warm and also I have to hold the power button until the BIOS forces a hard reboot to regain access to the Ubuntu login screen. It seems like something is hanging on shutdown. Is there a way to find out what it might be?
I also tried to force shut down the Surface by holding down the power button while the Linux desktop is active and from the login screen. Something is still staying on, as the battery is draining and the Surface remains warm to the touch in both circumstances. I have also noted that the battery is occasionally not charging when the Surface is powered back on, requiring the power connection be disconnected and reconnected to begin charging again.
Edit 3 - Okay, so using alive USB still causes this issue. I should have been clearer on my use of linux mint. The mint install went well at fist, but the install bricked itself at the first update, an I had no choice but to reinstall ubuntu. I went through the (very few) BIOS options. The only thing I could think to try to disable us LAN connection in BIOS. This setting had no effect. When I shut down the surface, it seems to shut down. If I press the power button afterward, the surface does not respond. I have to hold the power button for ~30 seconds to force the surface to restart.
Edit 4 - Something I just tried is to force reboot to the login screen and then hold down the power button till the surface shuts off. This seems to completely shut off the surface. Not sure if this makes a difference or not.

I don’t think this is anything to do with Ubuntu. If you hold down the power button, that should force a shutdown independent of the OS - so there’s something up with your bios or hardware I think. That mint also had problems also suggests it’s not a problem with Ubuntu. Have you tried running a live USB session and then shutting down?
